# Rails - how to redirect, flash an error / notice, and download a csv in the same action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, redirect, render

I'm building a feature that allows a user to process a mass update of records via a csv.

I want the functionality to be, from the index page:

1. upload csv
2. return a flash notice of how many records were successful
3. flash a notice if any records were unsuccessful, and listing their ids
4. if unsuccessful updates were made due to invalid input, download a csv containing a list of the records w/ invalid input so that the user knows exactly what was entered improperly
5. redirect back to the index page

I'm having a hard time getting all of this to work together.  I can get the CSV downloaded and redirect to work, but then my flash notices don't show (because of the redirect, I assume).

This is more or less what I have right now:

```
def mass_update
    if current_user.has_write_permission(:article_update_via_csv)
      if params[:articles_mass_update_csv].nil?
        redirect_to articles_url, flash: { error: 'No CSV file was uploaded' }
      else
        logger.info "mass updating articles using csv file"
        results = Article.mass_update_via_csv(params[:article_mass_update_csv], current_user.id)
        redirect_to articles_url
        send_data generate_csv(results[:errors], filename: 'failed-article-updates.csv')
        flash[:notice] = "#{results[:success].count} articles(s) were updated successfully" if results[:success].present?
        flash[:error] = "#{results[:error].count} articles(s) were not updated: #{results[:error].to_sentence}" if results[:error].present?
      end
    else
      redirect_to articles_url, flash: { error: 'You do not have permission to use this feature' }
    end
  end
```

Comment: This is not possible in HTTP. A request has one response. A response can't both redirect and send data.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your redirect at the end of your else block.